# Third party script file in reactjs

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to use a external third party script file form outgrow.co in my website.My website is based on reactjs. The script file is supposed to generate a button.I have tried this script with html code and it works fine.But its not working for my reactjs code.
This is the code i want to add:

```
 <div>
                <div id='5cbead6c7771f625d56e46f0' data-embedCookieDays='10' data-embedScheduling='false' data-embedTimed='true' data-embedExit='false' data-embedTimeFormat='0' data-embedTimeValue='5' data-embedBorderRadius='0' data-embedFontSize='13' data-textcolor='#ffffff' data-bgcolor='#fb545b' data-prop='outgrow-p' data-type='outgrow-b' data-url='https://arafathossain571.outgrow.us/5cbead6c7771f625d56e46f0?q=1' data-text='Get Started'></div>
                <script src='//dyv6f9ner1ir9.cloudfront.net/assets/js/nploader.js'></script><script>initIframe('5cbead6c7771f625d56e46f0');</script>
            </div>
```

here is what i tried:

```
 componentDidMount () {



        const script = document.createElement("script");


        (function(){

            <div>
                <div id='5cbead6c7771f625d56e46f0' data-embedCookieDays='10' data-embedScheduling='false' data-embedTimed='true' data-embedExit='false' data-embedTimeFormat='0' data-embedTimeValue='5' data-embedBorderRadius='0' data-embedFontSize='13' data-textcolor='#ffffff' data-bgcolor='#fb545b' data-prop='outgrow-p' data-type='outgrow-b' data-url='https://arafathossain571.outgrow.us/5cbead6c7771f625d56e46f0?q=1' data-text='Get Started'></div>
                <script src='//dyv6f9ner1ir9.cloudfront.net/assets/js/nploader.js'></script><script>initIframe('5cbead6c7771f625d56e46f0');</script>
            </div>
        })();


        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do this like this:

```
componentDidMount () {
  const script = document.createElement("script")

  script.src = "//dyv6f9ner1ir9.cloudfront.net/assets/js/nploader.js"
  script.async = false
  script.onload = () => {
    // you can append your div here
  }
  document.body.appendChild(script)
}
```

Comment: Where should i add rest of the script.This One-


`<script>initIframe('5cbead6c7771f625d56e46f0');</script>`

should i declare it in another variable?

Comment: in `script.onload = () => { }

Comment: really sorry.i am still not getting it.should it be like this?

 `script.onload = () => {
            <script>initIframe('5cbead6c7771f625d56e46f0');</script>
            <div>
            <div id='5cbead6c7771f625d56e46f0' '.......></div></div>`